# Cannot set onClickListener for item in onBindViewHolder

Tags: kotlin

I've the following onBindViewHolder function defined:

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = getItem(position)
        context=this.context
        item.address="Otra dir"
        item.clickListener=View.OnClickListener {
          /* Code to do on clickListener*/
        }
        holder.bind(item)
    }
```

Whatever I try to set in /* Code to do on clickListener*/ never fires.

I've tried, for example, to set the following code:

```
Toast.makeText(this.context,"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Navigation.findNavController(holder.itemView)
                .navigate(R.id.loginFragment, bundleOf(REQUEST_ID to item.id))
```

Also trying to show only the toast, and so on.

But whatever I do, it never reacts to onClickListener.

On the other hand the item.adress has its value address changed to new value, one different to the initial one:

The model for the item is defined in the following way:

```
data class Asset(val id: Int?, val name: String?, var address: String?, var clickListener:View.OnClickListener)
```

The initial values for the Asset were defined in the following way:

```
 private val resources = LockApp.instance.resources
    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            _showLoading.postValue(true)
            delay(3000)
            _assets.postValue(
                listOf(
                    Asset(1, "Nombre 1", "Dirección 1", View.OnClickListener {  }),
                    Asset(2, "Nombre 2", "Dirección 2", View.OnClickListener {  }),
                    Asset(3, "Nombre 3", "Dirección 3", View.OnClickListener {  }),
                    Asset(4, "Nombre 4", "Dirección 4", View.OnClickListener {  }),
                    Asset(5, "Nombre 5", "Dirección 5", View.OnClickListener {  })
                )
            )
            _showLoading.postValue(false)
        }
    }
```

As already told, "Dirección [number]" is changed to "Otra dir", so I cannot grasp why "View.OnClickListener {}" is not changed by the one I've set.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

don't make it complected

i think, it is like you want to click on perticuler item in `recyclerView`

```
class Itemsadapter(val onitemclick: Onitemclick) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Itemsviewholder>(){

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Itemsviewholder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindto(getItem(position))

    }


inner class Itemsviewholder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bindto(item: Item){
            view.setOnClickListener {
                onitemclick.Onclick(getItem(adapterPosition))
            }
        }

    }
  interface Onitemclick{
      fun Onclick(item: Item)
  }
}
```

in `Activity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),Itemsadapter.Onitemclick {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
      val adapter = Itemsadapter(this) // pass this to constructer as interface
      recycle.adapter = adapter //set adapter to recyclerview
 }

  override fun Onclick(item: Item) {
        //do watever
    }

  }
```

hope you get the idea...